# Hardware labeled as splashproof safe from condesation?

Tags: bluetooth, speakers

Are hardware items, such as bluetooth speakers, tablets & phones, labeled splashproof (not waterproof) safe from steam condensation when you bring them into the shower for 15 to 20 minutes?

Comment: Product example? It all depends on the IP rating. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_Code

Comment: JBL Xtreme.  Not sure on its IP rating, but it's labeled as splashproof.

Comment: Every product would have to be environmentally qualified separately. An item can be completely waterproof and survive for 3 hours underwater (high IP rating) and yet have a silicone seal which is semi permeable to water vapour and therefore not 100% suitable for "bathroom" environments.  A generalisation cannot be made on broad categories of products and must be made by each and every products designer.

Comment: If the question is modified to be specific about the hardware I am willing to vote to reopen

Answer (score 1):

The *specific* item you mention in the comments has a "Specs and support" section which has an "FAQs" tab, wherein appears:

> **Can I place my Xtreme in the bathroom, where it is humid, and it may be splashed with water?**
>     Yes, steam and drops of water in a bathroom are fine.

You can **only** apply that to the JBL Xtreme and you cannot assume that any other item labelled "splashproof" is also safe from condensation.